# How to persist Cache Store To a Relational database

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan

Is there any way to persist cached objects in infinispan Cached store  to a relational database Table?Iwas trying to do it as a Cacheloader.

```
 <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedCacheStore" fetchPersistentState="true" ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
    <properties>
     <property name="stringsTableNamePrefix" value="ISPN_STRING_TABLE"/>
     <property name="idColumnName" value="ID_COLUMN"/>
     <property name="dataColumnName" value="DATA_COLUMN"/>
     <property name="timestampColumnName" value="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN"/>
     <property name="timestampColumnType" value="BIGINT"/>
     <property name="connectionFactoryClass" value="org.infinispan.loaders.jdbc.connectionfactory.PooledConnectionFactory"/>
     <property name="connectionUrl" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DB;create=true"/>
     <property name="userName" value="user"/>
     <property name="password" value="password"/>
     <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
     <property name="idColumnType" value="VARCHAR(255)"/>
     <property name="dataColumnType" value="BLOB"/>
     <property name="dropTableOnExit" value="false"/>
     <property name="createTableOnStart" value="true"/>

    </properties>
 </loader>
```

From This keys and values are store in ISPN_STRING_TABLE_TEST_STORE where `<`namedCache name="TEST_STORE">. it saves keys in ID column and Values  in DATA_COLUMN as a Blob.I want to Put this Blob Contain data into a relational database(Not as Object).As a example when I put a Employee object in Cache it should put database table as a Employee table with emplyee properties as a fields in That table.(Emp Name,Age.. etc).Is there a way to Do this?

Answer (score 3):

There's an example in [Infinispan Data Grid Platform Book](http://www.packtpub.com/infinispan-data-grid-platform/book) which describes how to configure a **JdbcStringBasedCacheStore** using MySQL as relational database. In this example a Data source is used in the Connection URL, however it shouldn't be difficult to adapt it to your needs.Hope it helps. 
Regards

```
<loaders>
    <loader
        class="org.infinispan.loaders.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedCacheStore"
        fetchPersistentState="true" ignoreModifications="false"
        purgeOnStartup="false">
        <properties>
            <property name="stringsTableNamePrefix" value="ISPN_STRING_TABLE" />
            <property name="idColumnName" value="ID_COLUMN" />
            <property name="idColumnType" value="VARCHAR(255)" />
            <property name="dataColumnName" value="DATA_COLUMN" />
            <property name="dataColumnType" value="TRUE" />
            <property name="timestampColumnName" value="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" />
            <property name="timestampColumnType" value="BIGINT" />
            <property name="connectionFactoryClass"
                value="org.infinispan.loaders.jdbc.
    connectionfactory.PooledConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="connectionUrl" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" />
            <property name="userName" value="xxxx" />
            <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="dropTableOnExit" value="true" />
            <property name="createTableOnStart" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </loader>
</loaders>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use infinispan as  Cache loader  write JPA or Hibernate support.https://community.jboss.org/thread/149211  .Its  support cache entries write to DB as a BLOB. If you can Provide Cache loader JPA write support  example much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Things seem to have changed. This seems to work with Infinispan 5.2 and 5.3.

```
   <loaders [...]>
      <stringKeyedJdbcStore
            xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:5.2"
            fetchPersistentState="false"
            ignoreModifications="false"
            purgeOnStartup="false">
         <dataSource jndiUrl="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" />
<!--
         <connectionPool connectionUrl="jdbc:mysql://[host][:port]/[database]"
                         username="xxxx"
                         password="xxxx"
                         driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
-->
         <stringKeyedTable dropOnExit="true"
                           createOnStart="true"
                           prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE">
            <idColumn name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
            <dataColumn name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
            <timestampColumn name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
         </stringKeyedTable>
      </stringKeyedJdbcStore>
   </loaders>
```

Uses xmlns [`urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:5.2`](http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-5.2.xsd) (schemaLocation at link)

Comment: Shadow Creeper, thanks for your answer. I would vote for it but I do not have enough reputation for that. I'm using infinispan 5.3 with a postgresql database and it's working "connectionPool". Just had to add the infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-5.3.0.Final.jar and the c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar to my build.